# Angular populate input date from firebase data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, firebase, ionic-framework

I have this data structure in my firebase database

```
"dkt" : {
    "-KbzLbwQHzkFLkPLGhxN" : {
      "comment" : "",
      "date" : "2017-02-02T15:04:53.336Z",
      "name" : "Mamma Mia",
      "otherType" : "",
      "price" : 19.57,
      "type" : "Entertainment"
    },
...
```

This data is being retrieved by my service

```
.service('dktService', ["$firebaseObject", function($firebaseObject){
    var getDkt = function(dktKey){
        var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('/dkt/' + dktKey);
        return $firebaseObject(dbRef);
    };

    return {
        getDkt: getDkt
    };
}]);
```

And my service is being called by my controller and stored in my formData scope variable

```
$scope.formData = dktService.getDkt($stateParams.dktKey);
```

This data is being put into my ionic application form controls, so people can update it. All the inputs are displaying correctly except for the input with type `date` and my select dropdown.

This is my input date

```
<label class="item item-input" name="date">
  <span class="input-label">Date</span>
  <input type="date" placeholder="" ng-model="formData.date" required="">
</label>
```

And it's throwing me this exception

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2017-02-02T15:04:53.336Z` to be a
>   date

So I tried converting it to a date like so

```
$scope.formData = ReceiptsService.getReceipt($stateParams.receiptKey);
$scope.formData.date = new Date($scope.formData.date);
```

But it's still throwing the same error and the input date is still not changing to the correct date.

The strange things is, when I try logging my formData variable, it returns me an object

```
console.log($scope.formData)

e
$$conf: Object
$id: "-KbzLbwQHzkFLkPLGhxN"
$priority: null
comment: ""
date: "2017-02-02T15:04:53.336Z"
name: "Mamma Mia"
otherType: ""
price: 19.57
typeCost: "Entertainment"
__proto__: Object
```

But when I log it while looking for 1 of it's properties it returns `Invalid Date`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of angularfire are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.0.1